# Importing functions from a module located in parent folder to script

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I know imports are a common headache but none of the other solutions worked for me.

I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import functions from a module inside the parent folder of my script. Here is the folder structure.

- python_tools

  - command_line

    - cli_script.py
  - utils.py

cli_script.py:

```
from python_tools.utils import foo

def bar():
   foo()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    bar()
```

utils.py:

```
def foo():
    return x

def foo2():
    return y
```

This works in PyCharm when I hit 'Run', but I get the aforementioned error when running it from the command line with `python3 cli_script.py`.

I've also tried `python3 -m cli_script.py` which is the same error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_tools'`

From the other answers I gather that this has something to do with my `sys.path`. They mostly suggest modifying it in some way in the script, but that seems hacky / non-pythonic.

The idea is to have a module with a bunch of functions which are then imported recipe-style into a bunch of tools that are segregated into different directories. All of these tools will be scripts (if _name__ == _main__).

Please let me know if there's a better directory structure or if this isn't possible without hacky workarounds.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this *will* actually work once you `pip install` your package, even with as little as the [`--editable`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options) option intended for local testing. Because the Python interpreter will then be able to find your package, `python_tools`, on the module search path and take it from there.

I do not know about the PyCharm magic that seems to be going on. But, yes, you could add the parent folder "manually" to the module search path. For example, like so:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

That would usually do it. If the relative path `..`  doesn't cut it, or seems too "hacky", you could also get to the absolute path of your script from the pre-defined `__file__` attribute and using functions from [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or methods from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (and converting to `str` in order to `append` to `sys.path`).

The better directory structure might be to just have `utils.py` in the same folder as your command line scripts, or in a subfolder, as a module inside a package. That's because the directory of the script, when directly executed by the interpreter, is always on the module search path.

Answer (score 0):

All of John's solutions work and I basically went with the last one, but want to formalize the issue I was experiencing (and now understand better).

Python's `sys.path` is built based on the execution context. Since I was executing the script from different directories, imports were relative to that context.

I fixed the issue by hardcoding the relative import by adding:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

to the top of the cli_script.py. This is the most portable solution.

A more elegant solution is to pip install utils.py so it will always be on `sys.path` and can be imported by any module/script.

You could also add a PYTHONPATH environment variable to your bash profile, but I think that solution is the worst of all worlds.

Chris Yeh's incredible [write-up](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html) helped me wrap my head around this, see Case #4.